# Como tener acceso a una aplicacion .war desplegada en weblogic desde otra red

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic, windows-server-2012, war

Buenas tardes tengo un problema lo que pasa es que hice una aplicación con spring-boot entonces sace el archivo .war y lo desplegue en weblogic todo eso lo hize en un servidor con windows server 2012 entonces abre todo normal la aplicación entonces desplegó bien mi aplicacion en el servidor pero ahora quiero tener acceso a ese sistema desde otra maquina que no esta en la misma red del servidor.
En el servidor se ingresa con la url : **localhost:7001/nombre-del-proyecto**
y para entrar por otra maquina que esta en la misma red que ese servidor seria:
**ip-del-servidor:7001/nombre-del-proyecto** y da todo normal pero ahora yo quiero ingresar por otra maquina que no esta en la misma red del servidor como se podria hacer eso.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que crear una NAT o un port forwarding para ello, también podrías crear una VPN para poder darle acceso únicamente a ese segmento de red, formas hay muchas, pero la más adecuada sería sabiendo lo siguiente:

1).- Quien intenta ingresar ¿lo hará a través de una ip pública de tu red?
2).- ¿Tienes acceso para administrar la red?

Espero las respuestas para sugerirte la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Saludos

Comment: Si eso de la VPN era lo que estaba viendo que seria lo mejor porque solo tienen que ingresar algunas maquinas del lugar donde trabajo solo que esas maquina que tienen que ingresar estan en una red y el servidor esta en otra. Como seria si fuera con ip publica y no tengo acceso para administrar la red.

Comment: Primero deberás de contar con un ip publica, luego armar un servidor de vpn (te recomiendo strongswan ipsec v2), limitas el acceso a 2 máquina y listo, pero si consigues la ip pública y el server ya podrías hacerlo, de lo contrario deberás solicitar acceso al administrador de red, para llegar de un segmento a otro.

Comment: He visto tutoriales que usan una dirección ip externa que esta asociada a una interfaz externa esa seria la ip publica o seria pedir una ip publica al administrador de red ? y una consulta hay paginas que te dicen tu ip publica con esa no se podria hacer ?

Comment: Si se podría hacer, pero si tienes un firewall entre la ip pública y la red (en el 99% de los caso así es), no podrás hacerlo.